# OpenGL context and thread error with QGLWidget

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl

I'm working on the migration, from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.5, of a quite big app using a QGLWidget.

My error is "Cannot make QOpenGLContext current in a different thread".

What I understood about this error is that, as the error say, the openGL context can only be binded to one thread, and only this thread can use the context.

Old code was like :

```
myQGLWidget->makeCurrent();

.. some openGL

myQGLWidget->doneCurrent();
```

This was working in Qt 4.8, with some thread lock to avoid concurrent call to that "makeCurrent".

After reading all what I could on the subject, my last try was :

```
myQGLWidget->context()->moveToThread(QThread::currentThread());
myQGLWidget->context()->makeCurrent();
... openGL again
myQGLWidget->context()->doneCurrent();
```

I still get the same error...

I'm a bit confused about how it's supposed to work, can someone help me ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about a combination of two things:

1. QGLContext in Qt 5 is a small wrapper around QOpenGLContext;
2. QOpenGLContext is-a QObject (hence, it has [QObject semantics when it comes to threading](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity)), and for some reason it also employs a fatal check that forbids you to call `makeCurrent` on it from a thread different than the thread it has affinity with ("affinity" here being the QObject concept).

If you're in control of both threads the best thing to do might be simply creating a new `QGLContext`, sharing with your QGLWidget's context; and then move and use this new context into the thread. You still need the locking you already have -- you can't make two contexts current on the same surface.

More in general, this is recognized as a limitation of QOpenGLContext. I've already prepared a patch for Qt 5.8 to try to get rid of it, you can find it [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/155170/).

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm still lost. I'm ok to prevent calling makeCurrent form a different thread. [This Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html), section threading, is telling me that I have to use `moveToThread`, which doesn't work (calling `thread()` give the same result before and after `moveToThread`). In my case, I got a thread loading data, which also make some openGL calls (glGenBuffers). So it's one widget, one context, but two threads (sorry, I may have explained this before).

Comment: Sorry, I misread one particular line of your code: `myQGLWidget->context()->moveToThread(QThread::currentThread());` is wrong. You can't do that. You can only push from the thread owning the context into the new thread, not pull from the new thread.

Comment: Oh... Thanks a lot ! Then I'll use your Qt patch solution.

Comment: Well, or just change your code to "behave" as Qt expects.